# add data to database from front

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I looks many site and I can't find this. I am new with create components for joomla. I need one simple example how to add data from front to database tables in joomla 2.5 MVC Format. if you can send me any tutorial or write here some example I will be grateful. thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the example for insert the data to the database tables.

```
$db                             = JFactory::getDBO();
$shipping_details                   = new stdClass();
$shipping_details->pid              = $data['pid'];
$shipping_details->name         = $data['sname'];
$shipping_details->address          = $data['saddress'];
$shipping_details->city         = $data['scity'];

$stored_details                 = $db->insertObject('#__shipping_details', $shipping_details);
```